# Information Security Thesis idea

Tags: authentication, nfc

I need advice. 
Currently I'm doing my Masters in Information Assurance, and I only have my Thesis left to graduate. I chose a topic for my thesis but for some reason I don't feel confident that it's worth being a thesis topic. 
The idea is to see if it is secure and trustworthy to have an NFC enabled tag as an authentication method. To elaborate more:

"Let's say you want to sign in to your email account and other services using your smartphone. You simply grab your NFC tag and tap it with the phone and you will be signed in to the services automatically without any other user interaction"

The user, of-course is going to have his/her credentials entered for once and the information will be encrypted and stored on the NFC tag and the encryption key will be stored in the phone. When the user taps, the credentials will be sent and read by the remote server.
"I'm thinking about having a authentication token similar to the one Visa uses with Apple pay"

My project would be implementing a simple email server, to implement that concept.

Would that idea be worthy to consider as a thesis topic?

Comment: This does not appear on the scope of infoSec

Comment: As a thesis topic? You need to talk to your thesis advisor. As a worthy topic to advance Information Security knowledge? You need to describe how it solves problems with other authentication methods. As you described it, it sounds more like a programming project than a InfoSec thesis.

Comment: The Yubikey NEO implements what you're describing via U2F, TOTP, and its own proprietary OTP protocol. Each of those is available via both NFC and USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar for mine, (also a master's in Information security and assurance), and if your program is like mine, you can expect some minor pushback about solving "business problems".

It was not enough to merely demonstrate a technical solution, but you would have to illustrate the non-technical problems currently existing, the details of how the system would be rolled out (purchasing, deploying, training, etc), costs of implementing vs not implementing, comparison to other existing credential systems...

They may want "more" than just an engineering project of a new sign on methodology. The plus side is, you may not be required to create a functioning prototype, and need only design it.